# How can i show the overflow:hidden content using javascript or jquery

Tags: css

I have a div content that has CSS:

```
height:700; 
overflow:hidden;
```

What i want to do is i want to create a button that says: expand

so once expand is clicked i want the css for that div to change from:

`overflow:hidden` TO `overflow:visible`

so know the div will expand to the height spcified in the css and it would be great if the expand button turns into collapse and does the vise versa when clicked

Comment: If you are willing to use jquery you could do this with the ui widget accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is your friend.  It is the perfect library for constructing basic DOM events like you've described.  Your code might look like the following:

```
$('#expand-button').click(function(e) {
    $('.my_div').css('overflow', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply but i now nothing about scripts only now about css and abit about html i already have jquery in my template so how do i make the button #expand button and where to place it

Comment: how do i add height:auto; to $('#expand-button').click(function(e) {
    $('.my_div').css('overflow', 'visible');
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery .css function to modify the value of a CSS Property.  http://api.jquery.com/css/.

You can also Use jQuery to replace on piece of HTML with another, eg. To change the button.
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: how do i add height:auto; to $('#expand-button').click(function(e) { $('.my_div').css('overflow', 'visible'); });

Comment: You can pass an object to the .css function.  Eg. .css({'overflow' : 'visible', 'height': 'auto'}).